# Laravel - Show users from the last 30 days

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel query that looks like this

```
$users = DB::table("users")
                   ->select('id')
                   ->where('accounttype', 'standard')
                   ->get()->all();
```

It is working and returning the id for all standard accounts, I am trying to limit it to only return results from the last 30 days, the date the user was created is stored as a timestamp in 'created_at'

Is it best to do this in the query or should I process the results afterwards?

Comment: It's best to do this in the query. Otherwise, it won't scale well when you have a lot of users.

Comment: Have any examples of doing it in the query you can link me to?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use carbon along with the `where` clause:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

$users = DB::table("users")
    ->select('id')
    ->where('accounttype', 'standard')
    ->where('created_at', '>', now()->subDays(30)->endOfDay())
    ->all();
```

As noted in the comments, do as much in the query as possible until you notice performance issues or your queries become unreadable.

Comment: @MahediHasanDurjoy If the accounts are from the future then yes your query could possibly also work

Comment: I would suggest use of `where` and not `whereDate`, so the resulting SQL query can benefit from any indexing on the date column. The code would have to be changed to compare a time of 23:59:59 though.

Comment: @miken32 I wrote this answer quite a while ago, so I'm a bit fuzzy. Would an index have any performance benefit for a query with a '>' or '<' operator?

Comment: Yes the index is used for all comparison operations. `DATE(created_at) > '2018-03-17'` cannot use the index because it's a derived value – the function has to be run for every row in the table. `created_at > '2018-03-17 23:59:59'` uses the raw column value and its index.

Comment: @miken32 - Thanks - I've updated the answer. Interesting I thought `whereDate` simply appended the `->toDateTimeString()` and nothing else (ie I thought it was merely a convenience method)

Comment: To filter on the date alone you still need to set that time to 23:59, and the `where*` methods all cast Carbon to a string for you. Took the liberty of making the edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it

```
\App\Model::whereBetween('date', [now()->subdays(30), now()->subday()])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
$thirty_days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-31 days")); 
$users_thirty_days_ago = User::where('accounttype', 'standard')
    ->whereDate('last_online', ">=" , $thirty_days_ago)
    ->count();
```

Comment: How does this improve on the other answers given to this 3.5 year old question? Please also format you code to ensure it can be read without horizontal scrolling whenever possible.

Comment: All the other answers are using Carbon. This answer does not. Some people prefer to not use libraries

Comment: The question is tagged `laravel`

Comment: My answer is from Laravel too. If you look closely, you'll see the User model used with eloquent.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use it**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    
    class tblUserController extends Controller
    {     
    public function getSixtyMonthUser(){         
            $date = Carbon::today()->subDays(60);
            $users = User::where('created_at','>=',$date)
            ->where('accounttype', 'standard')
            ->select('id')
            ->get();
            return response()->json($users,200);
        
        }
    }
```